# How to scrape text from a Class in Table Column in JSoup

Tags: web-scraping, jsoup

I have been trying my best to scrape the data from the following website

https://barbarapijan.com/bpa/Graha/Rahu/Rahu_06rashi_Kanya.htm

There is a  class="auto-style162" on this page when we inspect element and this class has a long paragraph which I want to scrape.

I am writing the following code to extract this text from table column which has the class but its not working. Can anyone please help me.

```
Elements para =   doc.select("tbody.td.auto-style162");
for (Element e : para) {
    System.out.println(e.text());
```